# Bound of derivative of Lipschitz continuous function

Tags: lipschitz-functions, upper-lower-bounds

I have a function $f(x) = g(x)^Tx$, where $f: \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, $g(x):\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, $x\in \mathbb R^n$.   Furthermore assume $g(0) = 0$, $\|g(x)\|$ is bounded and also the partial derivative $\|\partial g(x)/\partial x_i\|$ is bounded for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

Since $g(x)$ is bounded, it holds that $\|f(x)\| \leq \|g(x)\|_{\max}\,\|x\|$ and if $\|g(x)\|_{\max}=:L$, then $L$ can be considered as a Lipschitz constant.

Now, with this information, I am looking for an upper bound for $\partial f(x)/\partial x_i$. It is possible to find a bound $\|\partial f(x)/\partial x_i\| \leq \tilde L$ independent of $x$?

Since $\partial f(x)/\partial x_i = (\partial g(x)/\partial x_i) x + g(x)^T e_i$ it is clear that $\|\partial f(x)/\partial x_i \| \leq \|(\partial g(x)/\partial x_i)\|_{\max} \|x\| + L$.

I am wondering if I could obtain a better result. I considered using the mean value theorem, but at this point I got stuck.

Can anybody give me a hint how to say from this something about the bound of $\|\partial f(x)/\partial x_i \|$? Also, if I have an error in the derivation please let me know.

Comment: I heavily edited your question, feel free to reject the edit. Also, could you provide some more context on this question? Is it related to some exercise or a greater result you need for some specific purpose?

Comment: @Mefitico: It is not an excercise itself, it is used in a Lyapunov stability proof. In what point is the MVT wrong?

Comment: @Carlos: You wrote (∂f(ξ)/∂x)x=g(x)x, which is unclear if intended to be a gradient times a vector ($\nabla f(\xi)^T x$) (that would be correct) or a single partial derivative ($\partial f / \partial x_i$) which is a scalar, times a vector ($x$, which indeed would be wrong). Maybe "wrong" was a strong word, but this is misleading notation.

Comment: @Mefitico: Ok, I agree. Thanks for editing. For simple functions like $f = \arctan(x)x$ with $x\in \mathbb R$, a bound $|f'|\leq \tilde L$, can be found. However, with $\tilde L > |\arctan(x)|_{\max} = \pi/2$. Actually $\tilde L = \pi/2 + 1/2$. Do you have a hint regarding the more general case?

Comment: Can't really think of any good hints, but see my answer: I have a felling no such bound could be found, and attempted proving by counter-example. Maybe adding a few more assumptions would do your trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x)
&=
\lim_{t\to 0}\, \frac{f(x+t\cdot e_i)-f(x)}t
\\&=
\lim_{t\to 0}\, \frac{{g(x+t\cdot e_i)}^T(x+t\cdot e_i)-{g(x)}^Tx}t
\\&=
\lim_{t\to 0}\, \frac{\left({g(x+t\cdot e_i)}^T-{g(x)}^T\right)x}t +{g(x+t\cdot e_i)}^Te_i
\\&=
{\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\, \frac{g(x+t\cdot e_i) - g(x)}t\right)}^T x \,+\,g(x)^Te_i
\\&=
{\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x)\right)}^T x \,+\,g(x)^Te_i
\end{align}

Since $g$ is bounded, $g(x)^Te_i$ also is.
However, it not enough to know that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}$ is bounded to conclude that the term ${\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x)\right)}^T x$ also is.
It would seem one needs some decay condition on $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x)$ as $\lVert x \rVert$ increases.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be any constant vector and $g(x)=k\sin(||x||)$

Then $g(x)$ is bounded with $g(0)=0$. The partial derivative is given by:
$$
\frac{\partial g}{ \partial x_i} = \frac{k_i x_i}{||x||}\cos(||x||)
$$

So also bounded. Thus satisfying your conditions.

However even for the one-dimensional case with $k=1$:
$$
f(x) = x \sin(|x|)
$$

$$
f'(x) = \sin(|x|)+\text{sign}(x) x\cos(|x|)
$$

We have that $f'(x)$ is unbounded. Granted that this function is not continuously differentiable on 0. I'm thus suspecting that at least more conditions should be given so that there could exist the requested bound.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I also assume that further conditions may be necessary, like a decay condition, as Fimpellizieri mentioned in his answer. Also the sine fuction in your counterexample is not decaying, rather it is varying fast as x tends to infinity.